# does "at the height of his manhood" is metaphorical or it simply refers to his age?

Tags: meaning

does "at the height of his manhood" is metaphorical or it simply refers to his age?

Some of these photographs are in the author's possession, and surely
there is no more wonderful impression upon any plate than that which
shows Crookes **at the height of his manhood**, with this angel—for such
in truth she was—leaning upon his arm.

https://www.nfsa.gov.au/collection/curated/sir-william-crookes-spirit-katie-king

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe height of manhood refers to strength, virility, physical aptitude etc. and is not related to age.

Comment: so, it alludes to physical condition and appearance of Crookes? am i right. as you answered.